# Interpretation of composite of random variable

Tags: probability-theory, notation, expectation

Let  $~f:[0,1] \to[0,\infty]$ be a measurable function bounded by $c \in \mathbb R$. Let $X_1,X_2,..,X_n \sim i.i.d ~\text{uniform}(0,1)$.

How do I interpret the following statement:
$$
Var(f \circ X_1)\le c^2
$$
Does it just mean that $Var (f(X_1)) \le c^2$? and how is this true anyway? Is it proved in the following:
\begin{equation*}
f(x) \le c \implies f^2(x) \le c^2
\end{equation*}
and so 
\begin{equation*}
E(f^2(x)) \le E[c^2]=c^2 \implies Var(f(x) )=E[f^2(x)]-E[f(x)]^2 \le c^2
\end{equation*}

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: @Did would this still hold if $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ ?

Comment: Assuming that $f\leqslant c$, obviously not. Assuming that $|f|\leqslant c$, obviously yes.

Comment: @Did i thought bounded implied the latter?

Comment: Thus, no ambiguity left.